# Mailgun and laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, mailgun

I try to use mailgun and laravel 5.2 without success.

I created an account in mailgun.com. I validated the email adress and the phone number.

Here an axtract of what I see in mailgun.com :

[image]

In .env file, I entered that :

[image]

In services.php file, I have :

```
'mailgun' => [
    'domain' => env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN'),
    'secret' => env('MAILGUN_SECRET'),
],
```

And at least in mail.php file, I have :

```
  'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
```

And to send my email i code :

```
Mail::send('emails/emailValidationInscription', [
            'personne' => $personne
        ]
        , function($message) use ($personne)
        {
            $message->to($personne->email);
            $message->subject('validation inscription');
        });
```

It does not work, I have this error :

**cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate**

What's the problem ?

Thanks for your answers.

Dominique

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28858351/php-ssl-certificate-error-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate/32095378#32095378

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP - SSL certificate error: unable to get local issuer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28858351/php-ssl-certificate-error-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers. I have the response.

The Laravel 5.2 official documentation explains that "mailgun" works with the Guzzle library `"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.3|~6.0"`.

But a lot of persons changed that to `"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~4.0"`.

I did this change and all works fine now.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you could add the following to `config/mail.php`:

```
'ssloptions' => [
    'verify_peer' => false,
    'verify_peer_name' => false,
]
```

And use it like that only in local environment.